# Algebric equation problems

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find $a, b, c \in \Bbb Q$ such that:  $\sqrt[3] a + \sqrt[3] b + \sqrt[3] c = \sqrt[3]{\sqrt[3] 2 - 1}$.

Comment: My first thought was to try to solve this by 
converting to polynomials. For example, you could define t = a^(1/3) 
and u = b^(1/3) and v = c^(1/3), so that

  a = t^3
  b = u^3
  c = v^3
  t + u + v = (2^(1/3) - 1)^(1/3)

Now you have polynomial equations, and you can eliminate the t, u, 
and v variables (which you want to do because they do not need to be 
rational) by taking resultants of those four equations. But you end 
up with a horrendous mess.

Comment: Where did you find this problem? P.S. : Your last comment should be added in the question, not as a comment.

Comment: I'm explain my thinking steps if you can put any idea I'm pleased

Comment: apparently the answer is $a=\frac 19$, $b=-\frac 29$, $c=\frac 49$ but I don't know why yet

Comment: Great try  go on and you can do it